# jQuery validate won't call my script in submit handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've scoured the boards for hours, so please, no snarky answers.

The following will not call my form handler from jQuery

```
<body>
<h1>Request A Consultation</h1>
<form id="consult_request" name="consult_request" method="post" action="">
  <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="132"><label for="firstName">First Name</label></td>
      <td width="353"><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="input required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="lastName">Last Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="input required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label></td>
      <td><input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" class="input required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="emailConfirm">Verify Email Address</label></td>
      <td><input type="email" name="emailConfirm" id="emailConfirm" class="input required" equalTo="#emailAddress" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send Request »" class="button"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script>
  $('#consult_request').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form){
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({url: '/_interface/process/testvars.asp', type: 'post'});
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I'm only using layout tables bc it's legacy code. I know better myself.

My form is at /_interface/content/popups/request.asp

Comment: what is the problem? is it that the `submitHandler` is not called or severside script is not called?

Comment: Client side handler seems to be fine http://plnkr.co/edit/1yqD9mbxrxgoew2mR3tF?p=preview I'm not a asp guy so sorry if it is about server side

Comment: @ArunPJohny the jQuery runs fine. submitHandler won't call the url.

Comment: check your browser console, check the network tab of your browser developer tool, it should have an error message like status 400/403/404/500

Comment: no error messages. it won't pass any url i put in there.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the required attribute be outside of the class?

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td width="132"><label for="firstName">First Name</label></td>
  <td width="353"><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="input" required/></td>
</tr>
```